# Logistic / T-test p-values

Tags: regression, t-test, logistic

I have Score data: integer ranging 0-100 which behaves normally on a QQ plot.

The score is assigned to a subject which is either Normal or Diseased and it differs between two.

I tried 2 models:
- prediction of Normal or Diseased status based on Score
- t-test of means between 2 groups

Both gave me low p-value for the Score variable (t-test gave me the mean difference between 2 groups as well).

Which result is more relevant to the following question:
Does the score differentiate between Normal and Diseased?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a classification question. Have you looked into something like decision trees?

Answer (score 4):

Either of those will answer the question '*Does* the score differentiate between normal and diseased'? The more useful question, however, is '*How well* does the score differentiate between normal and diseased'? Diagnostic tests typically need to perform *considerably* better than chance before they are clinically useful.

The standard way of analysing diagnostic tests starts by plotting the [receiver operating characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) (ROC curve).

Comment: Very useful, very helpful.